# set custom data to a quote in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

**I want to set and custom data like "loyality point" to a quote by id or by cart id in magento 2.
How can i achieve this.**

Or

**Is there any way to set custom data to a checkout session by API in magneto 2?**

THANKS.

Answer (score 3):

First create a colum in quote table

`Vendor/Extension/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor/Extension/Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('quote'),
                'loyality_point',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'comment' => 'Loyality Point'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Then you need to set value for that column from your code

```
class YourCustomClass
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function updateQuoteData($quoteId, $loyalityData)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId); // Get quote by id
        $quote->setData('loyality_point', $loyalityData);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote); // Save quote
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is bad because it doesn´t respect Magento best practices and the upgrade script execution is also not the best option anymore.